# Javascript not working on more loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, document-ready

I have this script where it adds some effects on my items listed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ui.card.work .image').dimmer({
    on: 'hover'
  });
  $('.carouselCollaborators')
    .popup({
      boundary: '.ui.card.work',
    });
})
```

However, when I click

```
  = link_to_next_page @works, 'Load more...', params: params, :remote => true, id:'view_more', class: 'fluid ui basic button'
```

load more button coded above, javascript i mentioned above is not working on loaded items...

How could I fix this...?

Thank you for you time!

Comment: You trigger you **"effects"** script only once, when the document is ready. You should trigger it every time you need it (when the document is ready and when a new element appears). Are you certain that you need _JS_ for this though?

Comment: Thanks @Mihailo ! Do I need JS for this..? Thats a good question but I am working with Semantic UI framework and I don't want to mix different types of codes. So It will be great if I can get this working...

Comment: Ok then you should wrap the **"effects"** script inside a function, and call it when you need it.

Comment: I am assuming it already is...? those .dimmer and .popup script is already inside the document.ready(funcion(){ ... What do I need to change to call it so that those scripts will be applied to the ones that are loaded later on...?

Comment: Is that script inside `$(document).read()` all you need for the "effects" to happen?

Comment: Basically yes...!

Comment: Can you alter the function that adds the new items?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that... maybe write something rather than... ready(function(){...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling the **"effects"** script only on `document.ready` you need to call it when you add an item as well.

#### These are the steps you should take:

First make a "wrapper" function that does the **"effects"**

```
function card_effects(){
  $('.ui.card.work .image').dimmer({
    on: 'hover'
  });
  $('.carouselCollaborators').popup({
    boundary: '.ui.card.work',
  });
}
```

Then call it where you want the **"effects"** to happen.

```
$(function(){ // jQuery document.ready shorthand
  card_effects();
});

function that_adds_new_items(){
  /***functions-code***/
  
  card_effects();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help...! Much appreciated!

Comment: Not a problem. I'm glad I could help you out :)